# How to make the CV?

Tags: moderncv, cv

Am making cv in latex, code is given below, have three questions:
1- How to add photo to it, in the line #8, pass is the photo name in jpg, this code displays error about this line, so please correct me.
2- I want to make the text size smaller, I've changed it in line #1 from 12 pt to 8 pt but didn't get the small text.
3- Comment the line #8 and execute,see the dashes of CNIC number, how to correct them.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\title{} 
\photo[64pt]{pass} 
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Personal Information}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.40\textwidth}
 Date of Birth\\
 Place of Birth\\
 Gender\\
 Marital Status\\
 CNIC Number\\
 Mobile Number\\
 Email Address
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.55\textwidth}
 March $22, 1990$\\
 City\\
 Male\\
 Married\\
 $61101-4186635-9$\\
 $+92\; 321\; 588\; 3776$\\
 abcd@gmail.com
\end{minipage}
\section{Education}
\cventry{2013--2015}{MS}{Name of University}{City}{Country}
\cventry{2008--2013}{BS}{Name of University}{City}{Country}
\section{Professional Experience}
\cventry{September 2015--to date}{Visiting lecturer}{Name of University}{City}{Country}
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}
\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}
\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}
\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}
\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
\cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item  Person 3\end{itemize}}
\cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
\cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and       \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications} 
\clearpage
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want an 8pt CV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For **1.**, you have to use a name through `\name` so that things move past. It is natural that a CV is supposed to have a name to display (at least). If no, use `\name{}{}`.
2. The standard font sizes in LaTeX are 10pt, 11pt and 12pt. You can choose any one of them thats all. If you want more, use either `scrextend` or `extsizes` packages.
3. It is not clear to me what you want to do with those dashes. I assumed that you want them smaller. For this remove the `$`s so that the number is in text mode.

Further, I have adjusted your `minipage`s. The option `[ht]` should be only `[t]` as `[h]` is invalid. Also the `\cventry` takes one optional and 6 mandatory arguments (you have used only 5).

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[8pt]{extsizes}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{}{}
\title{}                               
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Personal Information}
\hspace*{\dimexpr\hintscolumnwidth+\separatorcolumnwidth\relax}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.40\textwidth}
 Date of Birth\\
 Place of Birth\\
 Gender\\
 Marital Status\\
 CNIC Number\\
 Mobile Number\\
 Email Address
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
 March $22, 1990$\\
 City\\
 Male\\
 Married\\
 61101-4186635-9\\
 $+92\; 321\; 588\; 3776$\\
 abcd@gmail.com
\end{minipage}
\section{Education}
\cventry{2013--2015}{MS}{Name of University}{City}{Country}{}  %% last {} added
\cventry{2008--2013}{BS}{Name of University}{City}{Country}{}  %% last {} added
\section{Professional Experience}
\cventry{September 2015--to date}{Visiting lecturer}{Name of University}{City}{Country}{}
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}
\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}
\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}
\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}
\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
\cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item  Person 3\end{itemize}}
\cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
\cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and       \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]